# Chat Feature In Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, chat, microsoft-teams

When Clicking on a team member and going into their contact and you click on Start Chat. It will open SFB. Is there a way for this to open inside of Teams? I apologize if this has already been asked a solved.

[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta3KJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way for this to open inside of Teams? I apologize if this has already been asked a solved.

Yes, it has been solved. MS use SIP protocol to initiate chat in the client, which is handled by apps such as Skype for Business and Microsoft Teams.

As test in my side:

[image]

Note:

- On MAC OS when there are no default handlers for the protocol, Chrome provides no errors/pop ups where as Safari throws an error indicating that the SIP address cannot be reached.
- If it not work for Chrome, please try it with Edge or IE.
- Make sure you have installed Skype for Business or Microsoft Teams(If installed, try to re-install.)

Hope this helps.